# Getting Error 'An internal server error has occurred' while passing invoice template html data from LWC to Visualforce Page to render as PDF

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, controller, attachment, pdf

[image]

Html Code :

```
    <div class="invoice_container"
        style="width: 100%; max-width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333; background-color: white;">
        <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 10px;">
                    <img src={imageUrl} alt="Company Logo" width="200" height="100" />
                    <h1><strong>Relecotech Software Solutions Pvt Ltd</strong></h1>
                    <p style="color:gray;">476, Gurukrupa Bldg, Chandan Nagar<br>Nagpur Maharashtra 440009<br>India<br>GSTIN:
                        27AAGCR4589L1ZM<br></p>
                </td>
                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: right;">
                    <p style="font-weight: 500; font-size: xx-large;">INVOICE</p>
                    <p style="color:gray;"><strong>invoice# INV-{invoiceNumber}</strong></p>
                    <div style="margin-top: 30px;">
                        <p style="font-size: small;"><strong>Balance Due</strong></p>
                        <p class="bal" style="font-size: x-large;"><strong>Rs {finalTotal}</strong></p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 50px;">
            <tr>
              <td style="padding: 10px;">
                <p style="color:gray;">Bill To,</p>
                <p>{customerName}, {customerCompanyName}<br>{customerStreet}<br>{customerCity}-{customerZipcode}<br>{customerState}<br>{customerCountry}</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="color:gray; text-align: right;">Invoice date:</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">{invoiceDate}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="color:gray; text-align: right;">Terms:</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">Due on Reciept</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="color:gray; text-align: right;">Due date:</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">{dueDate}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="color:gray; text-align: right;">#Reference:</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">PO12423</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

        <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr style="background-color: #3c3d3a; color: white;">
                    <th style="text-align: left;padding: 10px">#</th>
                    <th style="text-align: left;">Item &amp; Description</th>
                    <th style="text-align: right;">QTY</th>
                    <th style="text-align: right;">Rate</th>
                    <th style="text-align: right;padding: 10px;">Amount</th>
                </tr>
                <!-- Table rows for items -->
                <template iterator:item ={items}>
                    <tr key={item.value.id}>
                        <td style="text-align: left;padding: 10px;">{item.value.id}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: left; color:gray">{item.value.description}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">{item.value.qty}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">{item.value.rate}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;padding: 10px;">{item.value.amount}</td>
                    </tr>
                </template>

                <!-- Sub Total -->
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" style="text-align: right; padding-top: 10px;">Sub Total</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; padding: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">{subtotal}
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <!-- CGST9 (9%) -->
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" style="text-align: right; padding-top: 10px;">CGST9 (9%)</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; padding: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">{cgst}</td>
                </tr>

                <!-- SGST9 (9%) -->
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" style="text-align: right; padding-top: 10px;">SGST9 (9%)</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; padding: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">{sgst}</td>
                </tr>

                <!-- Amount Withheld (Section 194 J) -->
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" style="text-align: right; padding-top: 10px;">Amount Withheld<br>(Section 194 J)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; padding: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">(-) {discount}
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <!-- Total -->
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" style="text-align: right; padding-top: 10px;"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;"><strong>Rs
                            {finalTotal}</strong></td>
                </tr>

                <!-- Balance Due -->
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" style="text-align: right; padding-top: 10px;"><strong>Balance Due</strong></td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;"><strong>Rs{finalTotal}</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>


        <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;padding: 10px">
                <p style="color:gray; font-size: large;">Notes</p>
                <p style="padding-top: 7px;">Thank you for your business. Please refer to wire transfer instruction details</p>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;padding: 10px">
                <p style="color:gray; font-size: large">Terms &amp; Conditions</p>
                <p style="padding-top: 7px;">Any T&amp;C <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_company_law"
                        target="_blank">here</a>.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="generate PDF" onclick={pdfHandler}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

Javascript :

```
import generatePDF from '@salesforce/apex/pdfController.generatePDF';

export default class DemoInvoice extends LightningElement {
@api recordId
imageUrl ='https://relecotech.com/images/logo.png'

invoiceNumber = '123';
    customerName = 'Test Name';
    customerCompanyName = 'Sample Company';
    customerStreet = '146, Nagar';
    customerCity = 'Nagpur';
    customerState = 'Maharashtra';
    customerCountry = 'India';
    customerZipcode = '440008';
    invoiceDate = '17/04/2023';
    terms = 'terms';
    dueDate = '17/04/2023';
    subtotal = 0;
    cgst = 0;
    sgst = 0;
    discount = 0;
    finalTotal = 0;
    
    items = [
        { id: '1', description: 'Product 1', qty: 2, rate: 100, amount: 0},
        { id: '2', description: 'Product 2', qty: 3, rate: 150, amount: 0},
        { id: '3', description: 'Product 3', qty: 1, rate: 200, amount: 0}
    ];

    connectedCallback() {
        this.calculateAmount();
    }

    calculateAmount() {
        let amount = 0;
        let total = 0;
        for (let product of this.items) {
            amount= product.qty * product.rate;
            product.amount = amount;
            total += amount;

        }
        this.subtotal = total;
        this.cgst = this.calculateCGST(this.subtotal);
        this.sgst = this.cgst;
        this.discount = this.calculateDiscount(this.subtotal);
        this.calculateTotal();
    }

    calculateCGST(subtotal) {
        const cgstRate = 0.09; // 9% CGST
        const cgstAmount = subtotal * cgstRate;
        return Number(cgstAmount.toFixed(2));
    }
    
    calculateDiscount(subtotal) {
        const discountRate = 0.1; // 10% discount
        const discountAmount = subtotal * discountRate;
        return Number(discountAmount.toFixed(2));
    }
    
    calculateTotal() {
        const total = this.subtotal + this.cgst + this.sgst - this.discount;
        this.finalTotal = Number(total.toFixed(2));
    }

    pdfHandler()
{
    let content =this.template.querySelector(".invoice_container");
    console.log(content.outerHTML)


    generatePDF({recordId:this.recordId,htmlData:content.outerHTML}).then(result => 
        {
            console.log('attachment id : ',result)
            window.open('https://d5g00000irdatea3-dev-ed.file.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+result.Id+'&operationContext=S1')
                             


                        
        })
    
}
```

Visualforce Code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <apex:outputText value="{!pdfText}" escape="false"/>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Apex class : pdfPageController

```
    public String pdfText {get;set;}
    public pdfPageController() {
        pdfText = String.escapeSingleQuotes(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('pdfText'));
    }
}
```

Apex Class : pdfController

```
 
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Attachment generatePDF(Id recordId, String htmlData){
        Pagereference page = Page.renderAsPDF;
        page.getParameters().put('pdfText', htmlData);


        Contact con = new Contact(Id=recordId);
        Attachment objAttachment = new Attachment();
        objAttachment.Name='invoice.pdf';
        objAttachment.ParentId = con.Id;
        objAttachment.Body = page.getContentaspdf();
        objAttachment.IsPrivate = false;
        insert objAttachment;
        return objAttachment;
    }
}
```

I have made an invoice template in LWC, but I am unable to generate pdf from LWC. So I have passed html data to Visualforce page to renderAs PDF but i am getting Errors.

Getting Error: uncaught in promise:
message: 'An internal server error has occurred\nError ID: 951318054-143396 (323779648)'}
errorType: "fetchResponse"
ok: false
status: 500
statusText: "Server Error"

Please reply if you have any solution or any other way to generate invoice pdf using LWC.

Comment: You can generate PDF with JS inside LWC. Check these two links Link 1 - https://salesforcecodex.com/salesforce/generate-pdf-using-jspdf-in-lightning-web-component/   Link 2 - https://absyz.com/how-to-generate-a-pdf-using-jspdf-in-lwc/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. External libraries like JsPDF  is an option but the LWC I have created will be of no use and I have to start all over again. I will have to learn external libraries which will take lot of time. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have a similar issue... were you able to find a solution?